# C# Задать количество раз срабатывания кода. Без изменения метода

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста как задать количество исполнения метода, без изменения самого кода.
То как я сделал, повторяет только по нажатию enter

```
using System.Linq;
namespace sluchainiy_simvol
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random sluchain_vybor = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int i = 6;
        do
        {
            const string chars = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю0123456789";
            var finish = (from vybor in Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 20)
                          select vybor[sluchain_vybor.Next(vybor.Length)]).ToArray();
            string resultat = new string(finish);
            Console.WriteLine("Случайные 20 символов - " + resultat);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (i > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну поместите код в цикл `for`. Или я не понял, что вы хотите.

Comment: Я хочу чтоб программа сгенерировала заданное количество строк с выводом в консоль. И чтоб строки были разные.

Comment: Ну вот читайте про цикл `for`: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements

Comment: Я делал уже так, но это работает только по нажатию Enter. А нужно чтоб автоматом нагенерировало заданное количество строк.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Comment: Она у меня серая. Я нажимаю на нее и ничего не происходит

Comment: @Andreyco89 прицельтнсь получше, у всех происходит, у вас нет :) серая - значит не поставлена. Только не путайте со стрелочками голосования, сама галочка ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите вызов `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Спасибо. 2 дня бился не мог понять почему не работает